# Why use force unwrapping in this example?

Tags: swift, option-type

```
let john = Person()
john.residence = Residence()

let johnsAddress = Address()
johnsAddress.buildingName = "The Larches"
johnsAddress.street = "Laurel Street"

john.residence!.address = johnsAddress
```

The above example is in Apple Language Guide.

Why did you use force unwrapping (exclamation mark) in the last line?

Is there a difference between `!` and `?` in this example?

Comment: Prior to the last beta or two, you could not assign to an optional chaining expression; to accomplish the same thing would require a more complicated series of statements. It could be that this example was written before the change in the betas, and at the time they wrote it they didn't want to go into the complicated way of handling optionals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A forced unwrapping is used when it's know that the optional has a non nil value. Using it on an optional with nil value generates a runtime exception.

The normal unwrapping instead is conditional. If `john.residence` is `nil`, then whatever is after it is ignored, and no error is generated (see [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_356)). The statement simply doesn't do anything, hence no assignment takes place.

The reason why the forced unwrapping exists is that it avoids checking for nils when it's known it has a value. For instance let's suppose you want to print to the console the content of a `String` variable:

```
let x: String?
print("\(x)")
```

If you initialize the variable instead, it will print something you wouldn't probably expect:

```
let x: String? = "Test"
print("\(x)") // Prints "Optional("Test")"
```

That happens because `x` is an `Optional` and not a `String` type.
To fix that, you force the unwrapping using the exclamation mark:

```
print("\(x!)") // Prints "Test"
```

Comment: Thanks again after the last time.